# Is there any plug-in or library to validate a set of form elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am a noivce at JQuery.

I'm curious about if there is any plug-in or libraries to help developers validate whether **any input value** over **a set of form elements** is not entered (empty string).

I can just think of using a function to achieve this feature. Any better idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[validate plugins in jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)**

Answer (score 1):

You can implement one, it's not that hard (for strings, at least):

```
function is_empty(input){
    input = input.replace(/\s/g, '');
    if(input.length <= 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

It's simple, small and suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [YAV](http://letmehaveblog.blogspot.com/2007/08/easy-client-side-web-forms-validations.html), which lets you define the validation rules as HTML labels.